# SDL with C - Blocks remains after being played

Tags: c, sdl, game-development, sdl-image, sdl-mixer

I have been working on a game that is a Stacker. Everything works fine, but after you have played and started over the blocks from the previous game still remain there.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BASE_TIME_INTERVAL 80
#define SPEED_INCREASE 1.03
#define GAME_ROWS 15
#define GAME_COLUMNS 7

#define MIN(a, b) ((a < b) ? a : b)
#define MAX(a, b) ((a > b) ? a : b)

int array_matrix[GAME_ROWS][GAME_COLUMNS];

//void save();

int credit = 0;
int in = 0;
int out = 0;

int inGame = 0;

static SDL_Surface *screen;

//Sprites
static SDL_Surface *square;
static SDL_Surface *background;
static SDL_Surface *grid;
static SDL_Surface *main_ui;
static SDL_Surface *award;

//Text Credits Sprites
static SDL_Surface *credits;
static SDL_Surface *number;

//Sounds
Mix_Chunk *soundPlace = NULL;
Mix_Chunk *soundGameOver = NULL;
Mix_Chunk *soundCredit = NULL;

FILE * fptr;

void print_board() {
    int i, j;
    SDL_Rect src, dest;     

        for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 7 ; j++) {
                if (array_matrix[i][j] == 1) {

                    src.x = 0;
                    src.y = 0;
                    src.w = 65; 
                    src.h = 65;

                    dest.x = j * 67 + 227;
                    dest.y = i * 67 + 240;
                    dest.w = 65;
                    dest.h = 65;        

                    SDL_BlitSurface(square, &src, screen, &dest);
                
                }
            }
        }
    }

void update_board(int x_pos, int length, int level) {
    int underflow_ammt = length - 1;
    int j;

    if (x_pos < underflow_ammt)
        length = length - (underflow_ammt - x_pos);

    x_pos = MAX(0, x_pos-underflow_ammt);

    for (j = 0; j < GAME_COLUMNS; j++) 
        array_matrix[GAME_ROWS - level][j] = 0;
    
    for (j = x_pos; j < x_pos + length; j++) {
        array_matrix[GAME_ROWS - level][MIN(j, GAME_COLUMNS-1)] = 1;
    }
}

int get_new_length(int level) {
    int i;
    int length = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < GAME_COLUMNS; i++) {
        if (array_matrix[GAME_ROWS - level][i] == 1) {
            length++;
            if (level != 1) {
                if (array_matrix[GAME_ROWS - (level - 1)][i] != 1) {
                    array_matrix[GAME_ROWS - level][i] = 0;
                    length--;
                }
            }
        } 
        if ((level == 4 && length == 3) || (level == 10 && length == 2)) {
            length--;
        }
    }
    return length;
}

void draw_background(){
    SDL_BlitSurface(background, NULL, screen, NULL);
    SDL_BlitSurface(main_ui, NULL, screen, NULL);
    SDL_BlitSurface(award, NULL, screen, NULL);
    SDL_BlitSurface(grid, NULL, screen, NULL);
}

void draw_credits(){
    SDL_Rect destCredits;
    SDL_Rect destNumber;

    switch (credit)
    {
        case 0:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/0.png");
        break;

        case 1:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/1.png");
        break;

        case 2:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/2.png");
        break;

        case 3:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/3.png");
        break;

        case 4:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/4.png");
        break;

        case 5:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/5.png");
        break;

        case 6:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/6.png");
        break;

        case 7:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/7.png");
        break;

        case 8:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/8.png");
        break;

        case 9:
            number = IMG_Load("assets/9.png");
        break;
    }

    if (number == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to load number png.\n");
    }

    destCredits.x = 300;
    destCredits.y = 1300;

    destNumber.x = 550;
    destNumber.y = 1305;

    SDL_BlitSurface(credits, NULL, screen, &destCredits);
    SDL_BlitSurface(number, NULL, screen, &destNumber);
}

void game_loop() {
    int time_delay = BASE_TIME_INTERVAL;
    int left_or_right = 1;
    int current_level = 1;
    int length = 3;
    int x_pos = 0;
    int quit = 0;
    int underflow_ammt = length - 1;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
                case SDL_KEYDOWN: 
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE && inGame == 1) {
                        length = get_new_length(current_level);
                        underflow_ammt = length - 1;
                        if (current_level >= 15 || length == 0) {
                            Mix_PlayChannel( -1, soundGameOver, 0 );
                            inGame = 0;
                            time_delay = BASE_TIME_INTERVAL;
                            left_or_right = 1;
                            current_level = 1;
                            length = 3;
                            x_pos = 0;
                            underflow_ammt = length - 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            Mix_PlayChannel( -1, soundPlace, 0 );
                            current_level++;
                            time_delay = time_delay/SPEED_INCREASE;
                        }
                    }

                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_2 && credit < 9){
                        credit++;
                        in++;
                        save();
                        Mix_PlayChannel( -1, soundCredit, 0 );
                    }
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_1 && credit > 0 && inGame == 0){
                        credit--;
                        out++;
                        save();
                        Mix_PlayChannel( -1, soundCredit, 0 );
                        inGame = 1;
                    }

                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE){
                        quit = 1;
                        exit(0);
                    }

                break;
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    quit = 1;
                    exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!quit) {    
            SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, 0x000000);
            if (x_pos >= GAME_COLUMNS + (underflow_ammt - 1))
                left_or_right = -1;
            if (x_pos <= 0) 
                left_or_right = 1;  
            update_board(x_pos, length, current_level); 
            draw_background();
            if (inGame == 1)
                print_board();
            draw_credits();
            SDL_Flip(screen);
            x_pos = x_pos + left_or_right;
            SDL_Delay(time_delay);
        }
    }
}

/*
void save(){
    fptr = fopen("data.xml", "w"); 
    fprintf(fptr,"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n");
    fprintf(fptr,"<Data>\n");
    fprintf(fptr,"  <credits>%d</credits>\n",credit);
    fprintf(fptr,"  <IN>%d</IN>\n",in);
    fprintf(fptr,"  <OUT>%d</OUT>\n",out);
    fprintf(fptr,"</Data>\n");
    fclose(fptr);
}
*/

void init(){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
    printf("Unable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(768, 1366, 16, SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
    if (screen == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to set video mode: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    if( !( IMG_Init( imgFlags ) & imgFlags ) )
    {
        printf( "SDL_image could not initialize! SDL_image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError() );
    }

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0){
        printf("Unable to set audio mode: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

     //Initialize SDL_mixer
    if( Mix_OpenAudio( 44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048 ) < 0 )
        printf( "SDL_mixer could not initialize! SDL_mixer Error: %s\n", Mix_GetError());

}

void loadMedia(){
    background = IMG_Load("assets/background.png");
    if (background == NULL)
        printf("Unable to load background png.\n");

    square = IMG_Load("assets/square.png");
    if (square == NULL)
        printf("Unable to load square png.\n");

    credits = IMG_Load("assets/credits.png");
    if (credits == NULL)
        printf("Unable to load credits png.\n");

    grid = IMG_Load("assets/grid.png");
    if (grid == NULL)
        printf("Unable to load grid png.\n");

    main_ui = IMG_Load("assets/main_ui.png");
    if (main_ui == NULL)
        printf("Unable to load main_ui png.\n");

    soundPlace = Mix_LoadWAV("assets/place.wav");
    if(soundPlace == NULL)
        printf( "Failed to load place sound effect! SDL_mixer Error: %s\n", Mix_GetError() );

    soundGameOver = Mix_LoadWAV("assets/gameover.wav");
    if(soundGameOver == NULL)
        printf( "Failed to load gameover sound effect! SDL_mixer Error: %s\n", Mix_GetError() );

    soundCredit = Mix_LoadWAV("assets/credit.wav");
    if( soundCredit == NULL )
        printf( "Failed to load credit sound effect! SDL_mixer Error: %s\n", Mix_GetError() );
}

void close(){
    SDL_FreeSurface(square);
    SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    SDL_FreeSurface(credits);
    SDL_FreeSurface(grid);
    SDL_FreeSurface(main_ui);
    SDL_FreeSurface(number);

    Mix_FreeChunk(soundPlace);
    Mix_FreeChunk(soundGameOver);
    Mix_FreeChunk(soundCredit);

    Mix_Quit();
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    init();
    loadMedia();

    game_loop();

    close();

    return 0;
}
```

I using:

- SDL 1.2.15
- SDL_image 1.2.12
- SDL_mixer 1.2.12

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you should learn more modern SDL2 instead of SDL1.2.

Comment: I know, but the reason I am using the 1.2 version is to work on hardware more old. But thanks.

Comment: Curious, what's that hardware?

Comment: It's a motherboard from the 2009 with only 2GB of memory RAM. Maybe it could Windows 7, but the HD that is using is running Windows XP.

Comment: I see. I'd suggest installing some Linux flavor on it (perhaps Xubuntu, [it's said to work even with 1gb of memory](https://xubuntu.org/requirements/)). This way you'll have a modern environment.

Comment: I will take a look, maybe it could run on the machine. My father want to use this computer to make a arcade Stacker. It because of this that in the code there is a credit variable.

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't immediately see the problem, but I see that `number = IMG_Load()` will leak if called repeatedly.

Comment: So when the number change, it must first clean the current one before it loads the other? I was thinking that it will just replaced the current one, but he still keeps in memory? Well, this probably means that the same are happening with the blocks. But how could I clean from the array in a efficient way the drawing occurring in the surface ?

Comment: It won't be deleted automatically. The idea is the same as with malloc/free (if you don't know how those work, there should be plenty of tutorials). The best solution is to load all images/sounds once during initialization, and reuse them afterwards.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will modify the code, maybe this is the problem. Sorry if I'm wasting your time.

Comment: If I felt I'm wasting my time, I wouldn't be helping. It's also a good idea to attach your assets in case me or someone else decides to try to run the code.

Comment: Hey, thanks men! You helped me a lot! It was my bad memory management of the array_matrix, now i freed the memory after the game finishes and start again, the blocks are rendering correctly. I really appreciate, I'm feeling now more motivate to study C. I will also try Xubuntu. God bless you.